# Is there a way to force a player running VAST tags to be silent even on user interaction?

Tags: html, audio, video, media-player, vast

Most VAST tags I'm using come with audio which is triggered on/off on user interaction. Is there a way to force a player to silence each possible source of audio without interfering with the video playback?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

Of cource you can teach the player to be silent. Obliviously this depends on the players implementation. If you want to start the player muted, go for the players API/implementation.

In fact your advertising partners will not like it, so I would recommend **not** to do so.

There is another thing to mention. I've seen (resp. heard) players playing VPAID somewhere in the background of the page. Meaning, there was a player invisible for the user, which was forced to play VAST/VPAID resources all the time. One of these VPAID (fortunately) wasn't well implemented. It wasn't possible to mute the Video as it was managed by the VPAID JavaScript loaded in an IFrame.

This is to be interpreted as: Whatever you do with the player, if you run VPAID you can't be 100% sure about what will happen. Or at least, you will have to make huge efforts to teach the player howto handle stuff like described.

Hope this was helpfull somehow - have a nice day.